# Handling response from Laravel-Notification-Channels/Telegram after message dispatch to channel

Tags: laravel, notifications, telegram, php-telegram-bot

I am utilizing the laravel-notification-channels/telegram package to enable my bot to send messages to a channel with admin privileges. The messages are being sent successfully. However, I require the message object returned by the sendMessage function. I must store this message ID in the database for future editing purposes. I have created an event and a listener, but as I am new to using them, I am still waiting for a response.

**Notification class**

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use NotificationChannels\Telegram\TelegramMessage;

class TelegramMessageTest extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @return array<int, string>
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ["telegram"];
    }

    public function toTelegram($notifiable)
    {
        $url = url('/announcements/');

        return TelegramMessage::create() 
            ->content("Hello there!\nYour invoice has been *PAID*")
            ->button('View Invoice', $url);
    }
    
    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function toArray(object $notifiable): array
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

**Listener class**

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\AnnouncementCreated;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Notifications\TelegramMessageTest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
use NotificationChannels\Telegram\Telegram;
use NotificationChannels\Telegram\TelegramMessage;

class SendTelegramMessage
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     */
    public function handle(AnnouncementCreated $event)
    {      
      return  Notification::route('telegram', env('TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID'))
                    ->notify(new TelegramMessageTest());
    }
}
```

**Event class**

```
namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\Announcement;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class AnnouncementCreated
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public $annoucement;
    public function __construct(Announcement $annoucement)
    {
        $this->annoucement = $annoucement;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel>
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [
            new PrivateChannel('channel-name'),
        ];
    }
}
```